# How to secure a webservice

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have a `webservice` with the name `http://mywebsite.com/myapp/findname`. The parameters it take is `name`. When i provide the name the return result will be the actual details of that person.

I have a worry about security in this instance. What happens if someone gets the `Webservice` URL (This can be got easily, by going though a web pages source). Anyone will be able to pass some data and retrieve information using my `webservice`.

So how am i able to avoid this ?

Comment: Uhm... this *is* used on a **public website** to **publicly** display information...?! You just don't want anyone to *directly* access the API but you require them to use your **public website** instead? If that's not the scenario we're talking about, clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically,
U can resolve this problem by the following step.
First there is a login API . In that api you need to provide the some token in the response.
and change it if user request for again login.
Than u can request for token in each request . if token is valid allow him to access the API response. if the token is invalid show the invalid request

Answer (score 1):

For security purpose u will ask a valid usertakon(which can be generated at the time of signup with random number), when u receive usertakon(as parameter) then first match this usertoken with your Database for verification that the user is valid or not, if user is valid then u give response otherwise restrict it at first level.